# Set environment variable in deployment config for container if variable is not empty

Tags: openshift

I am working with an existing Openshift deployment config where I can only change small parts.

The environment variables are set like this in the container config:

```
env:
- name: DATABASE_NAME
  valueFrom:
    configMapKeyRef:
      key: DATABASE_NAME
      name: ${DATABASE_CONFIG_MAP}
```

My problem now is that the config map, which is created in some other step, may not contain the variable. Is it possible to make this environment variable optional in the container DC (or even better, *not* set the environment variable if it is an empty string)?

Currently, the deployment will fail, mentioning that the key is not present in the config map.

I know that I could use `envFrom`, but this is unfortunately not possible in this specific deployment config.

Thanks!

Comment: See section 'Optional ConfigMap in environment variables' of https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tasks/configure-pod-container/configmap/ I am not sure what version of OpenShift you need for this.

Comment: Run `oc explain dc.spec.template.spec.containers.env.valueFrom.configMapKeyRef.optional` for details on the setting.